# getting blank data while scraping website using lxml

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to scrape a simple website and wrote some code too.
but I am getting blank result(no data).please help me /advise me where I doing wrong.I have tried scraping it using lxml  then I tried selenium too but no success.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml.html as lh
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://usa.kyoceradocumentsolutions.com/americas/jsp/Kyocera/wheretobuy_result.jsp?cat=2&zipcode=98413&city=&state=NJ')   

time.sleep(5.0)

content = browser.page_source

tree = lh.fromstring(content)

for d in (tree.xpath('//table/tr/td[@class="bodytxt"]/b/text()')):
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not handle frame by default, I agree with Key that its better to use direct url of that particular frame, and here is xpath for **name** and **address**
for name:

```
    //td[@class="bodytxt" and @align="left" and (b)]//b//text()
```

for address:

```
    //td[@class="bodytxt" and @align="left" and (b)]/text()
```

for both:

```
    //td[@class="bodytxt" and @align="left" and (b)]//text()
```

Comment: it is really working .Thanks mate.you are genius.Thanks again

Comment: Hi,I am again in trouble.I want to scrape http://hosted.where2getit.com/sharpsiica/index.html?form=locator_search&sku=ARM355&addressline=25303&zip=25303                        but I am getting too much wrong data.till now I have tried //td[@align="left" and (br)]                                                      but I am not getting correct data.i need only name and address.                                                             Thanks in advance

Comment: for name: (//td[@align="left"])[4]/a/text()
for address: (//td[@align="left"])[4]/text()